# Flask get request have inconsistent return

Tags: python, heroku, web, flask, server

I used Flask to build a mini server on Heroku. The server side code looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

schedule = {'Basketball': 'old value'}

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def get_all_schedule():
    return json.dumps(schedule)

@app.route("/update", method=['post'])
def update_basketball_schedule():
      globle schedule
      schedule['Basketball'] = 'new value'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I have one global dictionary `schedule` to store the schedule data. I use the post `/update` URL to update this schedule, and use the `/` URL to get the data, seems pretty straight forward.

I am testing this application on my Chrome browser. I called the post URL once. And then When I calling `/`, sometimes it returns the dictionary with `"new value"` and sometimes it returns the the dictionary with `"old value"`.  What is the reason for this behavior?

I am using a free dyno on Heroku.

My `Procfile` contains:

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku dynos occasionally reset, die, or are otherwise disabled. Because of this, the values of all variables stored in memory are lost. To combat this, you can use [redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis), or another key/value store to hold your data.

Comment: Just googled about Redis. Redis is an in-memory data structure store,  would it also suffer from Heroku dyno reset?

Comment: No, Heroku offers a redis add-on that isn't affected by this. See the [add-on page](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> I have one global dictionary `schedule` to store the schedule data

You can't rely on variables to maintain state like this.

For starters, [Gunicorn will run with multiple processes by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration):

> Gunicorn forks multiple system processes within each dyno to allow a Python app to support multiple concurrent requests without requiring them to be thread-safe. In Gunicorn terminology, these are referred to as worker processes (not to be confused with Heroku worker processes, which run in their own dynos).
>
> Each forked system process consumes additional memory. This limits how many processes you can run in a single dyno. With a typical Django application memory footprint, you can expect to run 2–4 Gunicorn worker processes on a `free`, `hobby` or `standard-1x` dyno. Your application may allow for a variation of this, depending on your application’s specific memory requirements.
>
> We recommend setting a configuration variable for this setting. Gunicorn automatically honors the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable, if set.
>
> ```
> heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=3
> ```
>
> The `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable is automatically set by Heroku, based on the processes’ Dyno size. This feature is intended to be a sane starting point for your application. We recommend knowing the memory requirements of your processes and setting this configuration variable accordingly.

Each request you make could be handled by any of the Gunicorn workers. And setting `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to `1` isn't the right solution for a variety of reasons. For example, [as Jake says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709606/354577), [Heroku dynos restart frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (at least once per day) and your state will be lost then as well.

Fortunately, Heroku offers [a number of data store addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores), including in-memory stores like Redis that might be a good fit here. This would let you share state across all of your Gunicorn workers and across dyno restarts. It would even work across dynos in case you ever need to scale your application that way.

Comment: what else can I do in my python code if I don't want to use redis only for that global? Because in node js my friend has created the same app using map = new map(); and this thing is working fine.

Comment: @BhaveshMevada, the best thing to do is to get your state out of your code. This is true of your friend's code, too. But to reproduce your friend's behaviour you can probably set `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to `1`, e.g. via `heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1` (though I _strongly_ recommend storing your state elsewhere).

Comment: Can I use MySQL to store flag value?

Comment: @BhaveshMevada, yes. Redis will give better performance, but any client-server data store will work. If you already have a database, feel free to use it.

Comment: Sir, Can I use g object here. I have seen in the other post suggested by you.

Comment: @BhaveshMevada, what do you mean by "g object"? Which other post are you talking about?

Comment: Are global variables thread-safe in Flask? How do I share data between requests?

Comment: No, global variables are not thread-safe in flask. I [commented about that on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869348/why-flag-value-is-changing-on-multiple-referesh-after-deploying-to-heroku#comment116464899_65869348). You could [use a session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43304363/354577) if it's device-specific. Depending how you set this up you might still end up using Redis or Memached or something like that… I do _not_ recommend using your filesystem for session data, especially with Heroku's dyno-local ephemeral filesystem.