# How can I use Flask WTForms and CSRF without session cookie?

Tags: python, flask, cookies, session-cookies, flask-wtforms

I have a very simple app that has no user management or any Flask-Login auth needs. It has forms, WTForms. All I want to do is collect some data submitted by the form. I could technically disable CSRF validation but Flask WTForms *really* urges me not to.

I'd like to disable flask session cookie in the browser because it seems unnecessary and I would need to put a cookie banner for GDPR compliance. So to avoid all that, I thought of disabling flask session cookie as follows:

```py
class CustomSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    """ Disable session cookies """
    def should_set_cookie(self, app: "Flask", session: SessionMixin) -> bool:
        return False

# App initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
app.session_interface = CustomSessionInterface()
```

But doing so leads to a `500` error: "**The CSRF session token is missing**". However, looking at the HTML that was rendered has the following csrf token rendered properly:

```html
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImI2ZDIwMDUxMDNmOGM3ZDFlMTI4ZTIzODE4ODBmNDUwNWU3ZmMzM2Ui.YhA2kQ.UnIHwlR1qLL61N9_30lDKngxLlM">
```

**Questions**:

1. What is the relationship between CSRF token validation and session cookie? Why is a cookie necessary to validated the CSRF token?
2. I tried enabling session cookies again, deleting the cookie in Chrome developer tools leads to the same error. So, indeed, session cookie seems to be absolutely necessary to validate CSRF token.
3. How can I use CSRF form validation without a session cookie?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You had a look on https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/csrf/ ?

Comment: server doesn't remeber you - it may use session cookie as databases ID to get `CSRF token` from database and compare with `CSRF token` from your form. OR it may use session cookie with some secret value to generate `CSRF token` and compare it with `CSRF token` from your form.

Comment: I don't know if Flask can do it but some frameworks could send extra data in ULR as i.e. `?sessionID=...` if they couldn't use cookies. But this way everyone can see these informations and Google's scraping bots can get them and keep in database and someone could get them using `Google Search` and reuse if they are valid long time.

Comment: @Misc08 @furas - I searched through the code base of WTForms and found that the token in the <form> hidden tag is validated using `session['csrf_token']` in the `self.protect()` method in the CSRF class. `self.protect()` is called before every request: https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/blob/565a63d9b33bf6eb141839f03f0032c03894d866/src/flask_wtf/csrf.py#L32

So I guess that answers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out from the code base of WTForms: https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/blob/565a63d9b33bf6eb141839f03f0032c03894d866/src/flask_wtf/csrf.py#L56

Basically, `session['csrf_token']` is stored in the session and compared against the `form.hidden()` tag (or `form.csrf_token`) in the HTML body.

This is not clearly explained in the docs. But the codebase makes it clear. I guess there is no way to do CSRF protection without secure cookies.

The downside of this is that you can't get rid of cookies. I suspect, one could build a [server-side session database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304363/simple-server-side-flask-session-variable), but then there are issues with scaling your Flask app horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if it helps you:

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/csrf/#creating-your-own-csrf-implementation

This allows you to create your own implementation of csrf token generation and validation in which you do not need to use cookies.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33128272)